Add preprocessor like prefix for C/C++ indentation
I want to extend the existing indentation capabilities for macro constructs which behave like preprocessor directives.
Consider the following code example:
void fkt() {
   const int a = 0;
MY_MACRO(foo bar)
   return a;
}

Here in the example I want macro MY_MACRO and the following line to be handled like a preprocessor directive (say #idfef). Note that there is no ; termination (and can not be in my case) and it is indented to the start of line.
I figured this could be possible if I could extend c-opt-cpp-prefix, however, this seems to be non trivial, because I can not figure out how to do it reliably. Can someone give me an example of how this could be done?
I may live with some niece functionalities to be not supported (there are a couple of constants and variables derived from c-opt-cpp-prefix), only the most simple case.
Might another approach be possible, like adding a new indentation context (souds like much work), or would there be a function I could advice trivially to get my desired result?
EDIT: wording and added tag cc-mode
